# CSS rollover working on one page, but not another

Tags: css, rollover, marquee

I'm replacing all Fireworks-generated table-based rollovers on my site with CSS rollovers; I've so far had luck with my menu bar, which works properly on each page on the site. 
Today I tried to update my main page's marquee (div id="titlemain" on theapplenewsreel.com), and while the rollovers seem to work fine on the staging page where I designed and tested said element (theapplenewsreel.com/titlemain.html), the code refuses to work when I integrate it into the page where I intend to use it. I've checked the link to the stylesheet; it points to the exact same CSS file. 
 Can anyone suggest a reason why the marquee's share links don't update on the index.html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the CSS to include px in the background position numbers:

```
#titlesharefb:hover {
    background-position: 0 -80px;
}
```

Comment: It's always the most obvious answer. Thanks!